# How to set defaultValue for boolean field in jaxb

Tags: java, rest, jaxb

While am trying to Marshaling and marshaling object with boolean properties with @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(BooleanAdapter.class) am getting 'null' instead of 'false' in json response.

my sample object and adapter classes are below.

public class Test 
{

```
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(BooleanAdapter.class)
    boolean b1; 

    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(BooleanAdapter.class)
    boolean b2; 

    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(BooleanAdapter.class)
    boolean b3;
```

}

public class BooleanAdapter extends XmlAdapter {

```
@Override
public Boolean unmarshal(Boolean v) throws Exception {
    /*
     * 
     */
    return Boolean.TRUE.equals(v);
}

@Override
public Boolean marshal(Boolean v) throws Exception {

    if (v) {
        return v;
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

in Marshaling am removing fields with 'false' value to store the response in database.
but when i getting json response is coming like below.

{
   "b1" : null,
   "b2" : true,
   "b3" : null
}

here b1&b2 values are false. i required value as false instead of null in response.

please help on this.